# Blue links and phone number in mail footer

Tags: html, css, email, footer

How can I disable adding styles and links in my e-mail footer? I have something like this:

```
Tel: 000-000-000, Tel: 000-000-000, http://my-web-page.com
```

And after e-mail has been sent recipient see blue links and hyperlinks like: tel: and href :/
How can I change this? I would like to disable all links or change color of them

Comment: Can you provide some html ?

Comment: Could you please show us what customers see when they open your email?

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the `<a>` tag the following css:

```
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: red;//or what color you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for telephones numbers use

```
000<span>-</span>000<span>-</span>000
```

which will remove the blue colour

and for < a > tags

you can give inline style

```
style="text-decoration:none; color:#040400;"
```

gmail don't support #000000 you can use any other colour which is close to black

you can also test your email here http://putsmail.com/ which is a best test tool for email

Answer (score 0):

What email client are you using?

Outlook: You may be able to create HTML/CSS in another program, and make it choose the colours / text decoration manually, then paste it in.

Lotus Notes: You can hardcode the colour and decoration of your link through the context menu on the text you're linking (or want to change the look of permanently)

Gmail: Not sure if that is possible. Gmail can handle html email, but its rich text editor doesn't show you html, so I'm not sure how you'd do that.

What you want to have, eventually, is something like this:

```
<a href="mailto:your@address.com" style="text-decoration:none; color: #000000;">your@address.com</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
a:link, a:visited{    
    color: <<your link color>>;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<div class ="disable-link>
Tel: 000-000-000, Tel: 000-000-000, http://my-web-page.com
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .disable-link{
    text-decoration:none!important;
    color: grey; //or what color you want
    font-weight:14px; //or what font-size you want
    width:580px;
    background:#ccc;
    height:auto;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

try **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manjunath_siddappa/19xusd70/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div>
    Tel: 000-000-000, Tel: 000-000-000,<a href="#">http://my-web-page.com</a>
 </div>
```

css

```
div{
    color:your color;
    background: your color;
    /*text-align:center;
    font-size:##;*/
   }
 div a{
       text-decoration:none;
       color:your color;
      }
```